# AWS - implementing network firewall for 1 VPC with 3 availability zones

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I need to implement aws network firewall for an environment that did not previously have one implemented.

I've seen various documentation that describes various topologies for implementing network firewall.

One of those is creating the subnets for the network firewall in the existing VPC address space, but it looks like each availability zone would need it's own separate firewall? Would these use the existing internet gateway/nat gateway? Do I just create 2 new subnets in the VPC network, and change the route table to route to the interface on the network firewall?

Another option is to bring up another separate VPC specifically for the firewall, on it's own subnet, and creating new route tables to funnel all traffic through this new vpc, and out a new internet gateway (and nat gateway?)

I would think it better to have a single network firewall that all traffic goes into and out of, however with the 3 availability zones, how would this work?